# Dockerfile single line `ENV` composing variables not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to compose two environment variables: first define a "root" and in the same line use that to create a composed one. In example, filename and append extension.

Doing this container,

```
FROM centos:7

ENV ROOT_VAR=stringy ROOT_VAR_TGZ=${ROOT_VAR}.tar.gz

RUN echo ${ROOT_VAR} $ ${ROOT_VAR_TGZ}
```

The output for `echo` is

```
stringy $ .tar.gz
```

But when splitting each variable in an individual `ENV` command is composed correctly.
Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile: Setting multiple environment variables in single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529121/dockerfile-setting-multiple-environment-variables-in-single-line)

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but I want to **compose second variable**, not only single line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is clearly explained in the [docker reference document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> Environment variable substitution will use the same value for each variable throughout the entire instruction. In other words, in this example:
>
> ```
> ENV abc=hello
> ENV abc=bye def=$abc
> ENV ghi=$abc
> ```
>
> will result in `def` having a value of `hello`, not `bye`. However, `ghi` will have a value of `bye` because it is not part of the same instruction that set `abc` to `bye`.

Comment: It is really bad explained, but it explains. Thanks.

Comment: So how can I do it if I still want a single liner?